# how do i set dynamic constraint for buttons in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, constraints

I have simple UIView which has two buttons named "Button1" and "Button2".
At certain conditions(suppose X condition), i need to show both buttons as shown in image1.

In another condition (suppose Y condition), i need to hide "Button2" and and also place it in center of UIView as shown in image2.

If you could provide me with example, it will be very much helpful to me.
I need to do this in objective only for iPhone.

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: Doesn't it just work when you put them in a (horizontal) stack view? Otherwise you can give button 1 two constraints on it's left side. Constraint A to button 2 and constraint B to the parent's edge, with a lower priority than constraint A. When you hide button 2, you should also disable constraint A...

Comment: @H. de Jonge - dont want to use stack view.

Answer (score 0):

I have done with 3 Buttons

You need to give following constraints..

- btn1 leading to its superview

  btn2 leading to btn1 trailing

  btn3 leading to btn2 trailing

  btn3 trailing to its superview

  btn1 equal width to btn2 -> Priority 999

  btn2 equal width to btn3 -> Priority 999

  btn1 top to its superview -> Priority 999

  btn2 top to its superview

  btn3 top to its superview

  btn1 width Constraint -> Priority : 750 , constant -> 0 Take IBOutlet

for all 3 buttons you also need to give height constraints.

After this when condition Y Occurs

Set btn1 width Constraint Priority : 1000  And you done

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'll need to have two sets of constraints, one for each layout (one button and two button). You'll switch between those sets when the view should change.

When you want to switch, you'll want to deactivate the first and activate the second. You do this with [`deactivateConstraints:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526066-deactivateconstraints) and [`activateConstraints:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526955-activateconstraints). For the layout with only one button, you'll also want to remove the second button from the view by calling [`removeFromSuperview`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622421-removefromsuperview) on it (and re-adding it when you switch back to showing two).

If you are using Interface Builder, you'll need to create [`IBOutlet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Outlets/Outlets.html)s to the constraints created there so that you can access them. You will also probably want to only create one set of constraints in Interface Builder, since they will conflict with each other if they are both active at the same time.

If you are unfamiliar with how to create constraints in code, this might help you out [Programmatically Creating Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH16-SW1)
.